# I tried wrote a code to prevent xlabels from overlapping each other in graph. But now, some labels are not showing up in graph

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, jupyter, exploratory-data-analysis

This the code I wrote :

```
carPriceNew = carPrice.groupby(['CarName']).mean()
carPriceNew.plot(y='price')
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
```

[I've attached the screenshot of my output here.(Please Click On The Text To View The Screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLHqI.png)

I expect to have labels not to overlap with each other and I want all the labels to be there in the graph.

Comment: where is Screenshot ?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to attach it. I have attached it now. Kindly go through it now.

Comment: I got issue, Its because you have too many xlables. python is treating carnames as a sequence and randomly giving xlables for each 10th car(assume).. you can try to plot graph for first 10 records.. it should be good.. 
But dont know how to fix such scenario where we have toomany xlables.. try to plot large line graph with large fix size..

Comment: As the x-axis is discrete car data, you should use a discrete plot too, such as a bar chart - you can use the kwarg `kind="bar"`.  This might also help with the label values - continuous plots like a line graph will scale the labels (as you would expect with numbers or dates).